# using sha512 encoder with symfony2 in_memory security provider

Tags: security, symfony, encoding, passwords, sha512

I'm trying to configure my symfony2 application to use the sha512 password encoder with the in_memory security provider, but I can't get it to work. I am getting the infamous "Bad credentials" error on login. Unlike most questions here, I do not want to get users from any database. I do not want to use FOSUserBundle. All I want is simply to replace the plaintext passwords in my security.yml with sha512 hashes.

According to http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password this should be as simple as setting the encoder and replacing the plaintext password with the hash, so that is what I tried to do:

security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: sha512

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin: { password: $6$randomsalt$mbd3sS15ibE.W7hkLqfQ0LNEQsUod7BOUD67g/oIb8uhqGfyAzaga3vgGaRJZn67VdHHfn.tnkKY9ffDVXw3C., roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
```

The password is "admin", the salt is "randomsalt" and the hash was generated by mkpasswd:

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512 admin randomsalt
```

Why is this not working? Does symfony2 expect the hash to be in some other format?

EDIT: things I've tried as well:

- generating the hash through PHP using `crypt($password, "$6$".$salt)`
- toggling `encode_as_base64` true/false on the security encoder
- specifying the number of iterations to use (default 5000)

Result is the same: "Bad credentials".

Comment: I'm not quite sure why would you use `mkpasswd` in this situation? Also, you might need to be using `php` and the `sha512` function to generate the password hash, rather than calling `mkpasswd`?

Comment: I used mkpasswd as a quick way to generate default format hashes for testing. I have also tried with hashes generated by php: `crypt($password, "$6".$salt)` (comment edited for code brevity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much trial and error, the only configuration I have been able to get working is the simplest case:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: sha512
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 1

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin: { password: c7ad44cbad762a5da0a452f9e854fdc1e0e7a52a38015f23f3eab1d80b931dd472634dfac71cd34ebc35d16ab7fb8a90c81f975113d6c7538dc69dd8de9077ec, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
```

That's a single sha512 iteration of the unsalted password obtained by `echo -n admin | sha512sum` or from any of the various online hash generators. I can't get it to work with anything created by PHP's standard crypt() or password_hash() functions. The docs don't specify a format. My app doesn't deal with users or passwords in any other way and I was rather hoping to use symfony's security component without writing custom user entities or password encoders. This is turning into an awful lot of work for what seems like a very basic thing.

Comment: I was just reading http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html#modify-security-yml where they give the example with `sha512`. It appears the password is encoded with `base64` before it is hashed. That was why the hashes were not working.

Comment: Yeah, it also appears there's something going on with curly braces in the password + salt concatenation. That cookbook entry says "you'll need to do a bit more work". I gave up and went with bcrypt instead, using ircmaxell/password-compat from https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat as per the instructions from http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password and that works. It requires PHP >= 5.3.7 though, so Debian Squeeze boxes are not supported. I can live with that. Thanks!

Comment: This answer works, but be sure to put quotes around the hash, otherwise yaml could recognize it as a number when it starts with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which is not elegant but working and allows any number of iteration unlike the accepted answer:

It uses the following class: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder

In any Controller (or whatever php file) add the following code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder;

...

$messageDigestPasswordEncoder= new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder;
var_dump($messageDigestPasswordEncoder); // you'll see the default options
var_dump($messageDigestPasswordEncoder->encodePassword('Hello', '')); // ouput the encoded password
```

In your security.yml, add the following code:

security:

```
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: sha512

providers:
    admin:
        memory:
            users:
                # password: Hello
                test:  { password: CYvx/IlZCmwdywJkE8X6FTAixdgaL1oq0u8Ij3o+2LIAyDkWHynQ5UCdWe78YQt5j4oMIIu7YjYYR2b3H7zbvg==, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }
```